# pip 6.0.6 installs setuptools 0.6rc11 on CentOS 6.3 with Python 2.6.6 installed

Tags: python, centos, pip, chef-infra, setuptools

pip 6.0.6 installs setuptools 0.6rc11 on CentOS 6.3 with Python 2.6.6 installed
pip 1.5.6 installed setuptools 8.2.1

Doing a pip update on setuptools gives the following message

```
# pip install -U setuptools
Collecting setuptools from https://pypi.python.org/packages/3.4/s/setuptools/setuptools-11.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=59cd761f2f2b926313bed7f83337e4d7
    Using cached setuptools-11.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: setuptools
    Found existing installation: setuptools 0.6rc11
    Can't uninstall 'setuptools'. No files were found to uninstall.

Successfully installed setuptools-0.6rc11
```

I'm using the [Chef Community Python Cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/python) to install everything and the cookbook hasn't changed since 25-Feb-2014. However the cookbook installs the the latest version of pip and that has been updated recently.

What have I done wrong?

**Update:**
I found that the `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info` file still existed.

deleting the file resolve the issue, however I would still like to know why the file still existed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to xavfernandez on github for providing the [answer](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2348).

The problem is that the version number of setuptools-0.6rc11 doesn't match the filename of the egg file.
Either deleting the egg file for setuptools or renaming the egg file to match the version number will resolve the issue.

If the version number and egg file in /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ don't match pip seems to get lost and upgrades and uninstalls of packages won't work.